# Code Error 9 In Modelsim

Tags: verilog, simulation

When I am trying to do simulation of the following program on Modelsim Altera  10.0d then gives Error : Code Error 9:
** Fatal: (vsim-4) ***** Memory allocation failure.

## Attempting to allocate 131072 bytes

## Please check your system for available memory and swap space.

The following is my code :-

```
module sipo (gsclk, sclk, rst, sipo_in, sipo_out, sipo_out_i, dcsel, blank, gs_enable);
   input gsclk, sclk, rst;
   input sipo_in;
   input dcsel, blank;
   output reg [47:0] sipo_out;
   output reg [47:0] sipo_out_i;
   output     gs_enable;
   integer i;

   assign  gs_enable = (~dcsel & sclk==1'b1) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

   always @(posedge gsclk, posedge rst)
     i=0;
   begin
     if (rst)
       sipo_out_i  <= 47'b0;
     else
       if (gs_enable)
         for (i=1; i<= 48; i=i+1)
           @(posedge sclk)
             while (i < 48)
             begin
               sipo_out_i  <= {sipo_out_i[46:0], sipo_in}; 
               i = i+1;
             end
           sipo_out <= sipo_out_i;
   end
```

Please help me if  it requires any change in verilog code?

Answer (score 1):

Your simulator should be giving syntax errors before the memory allocation error.

The `always` block has many errors. First it delete the line `i=0;`, it is assigned in the for-loop. This allows the `begin` block called on the `always` blocks triggered events. Don't use both for-loop and while-loop. Currently both dependent on `i` and if the code could run you would see `i` go 1 to 48 with no step in between, and `sip_out_i` would equal `{48{sipo_in}}`. Assuming not what you are intending and inefficient if it is.

Having a `@(...)` nested statement inside another block is legal verilog, but is a bad coding style. Synthesis tools and linting tools will give errors. Nested `@(...)` and `wait` statements are more intended for the test-bench framework, and even that is mostly discouraged.

You should use two always blocks. One running on `gsclk` and the other on `sclk`. `sclk` should fill `sipo_out_i`. `gsclk` transfer `sipo_out_i` to `sipo_out`. Handshake signals will be needed to synchronize the two blocks.